# Given a graph G, does a divide-and-conquer approach work to finding minimum spanning trees?

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

If given a connected graph G, split the graph into Ga and Gb. If you find a minimum spanning tree for Ga and Gb (called Xa and Xb, respectively), does connecting Xa to Xb with a minimal weighted edge still form a spanning tree? Is that spanning tree a minimum spanning tree?

This is my logic so far. I believe that connecting Xa to Xb *would* form at least a spanning tree almost by definition. (If there is a counterxample though that'd be helpful) However, I don't think it would always form a minimum spanning tree because depending on the structure of the graph, you may be able to remove an edge from Xa or Xb, then add the edge connecting them, and still have a tree. This may be the case in a situation where multiple edges of the same weight connect Xa and Xb at different vertexes.

Is my logic correct so far?

Comment: Tagging as `homework`; please use this tag in the future, thanks! =) (apologies if this is not homework; if so please remove tag)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are unfortunately misinterpreting; the community has no desire to censor you (in fact I firmly believe in your right of free speech). I was merely pointing out that taglines and similar comments are off-topic and against StackOverflow's policies. Additionally please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette as well as the criteria for upvoting and downvoting. Have a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct, that you don't always get a minimal spanning tree by just connecting Xa and Xb. But it is not necessary, that the edges connecting Xa and Xb have the same weight. See the following example:

Assume you have the following Graph G:

```
A-B-C-D 
| | | | 
E-F-G-H
```

Edge (B,C) hast cost 1 and (F,G) has cost 2, all other edges have cost 10.

Then you divide it in Ga and Gb:

```
A-B   C-D 
| |   | | 
E-F   G-H
```

Minimum spanning trees Xa and Xb are:

```
A-B   C-D 
|       | 
E-F   G-H
```

If you now connect them with the minimal possible edge you get a spanning tree with cost 61:

```
A-B-C-D 
|     | 
E-F G-H
```

But that's not a minimal spanning tree. A minimal spanning tree (with costs 53) would be

```
A-B-C-D 
|       
E-F-G-H
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, your counterexample helped me clarify my answer a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You should assume a solution and reverse-engineer a counterexample. For example, assume for a graph G, the minimum spanning tree is X.

- If you split the graph so that you only cut through X once, then the minimal weighted edge would necessarily be the removed edge and thus you cannot construct a counterexample.
- However if your partition cuts the tree in two places, you have a counterexample. You assert that you would only need to add in one edge, but by construction you cut the optimal tree in two locations, and thus you need to add two edges to reconstruct the optimal tree (and you also had an extraneous edge in one of your partitions). (See steckl's answer for a very clearly example of this.)

Your first claim ("I believe that connecting Xa to Xb would form at least a spanning tree almost by definition.") is correct; you can prove it using some facts about trees: a fully-connected graph with N nodes and N-1 edges is a tree, and a tree is a fully-connected graph with N nodes and N-1 edges (cycles cannot form). Or you can use an equivalent condition from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Definitions